# 'If-Elif-Else' Function Returning Truth Value Ambiguous - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Attempting to run a function to separate age of house into certain categories, and then create a new column in the original dataframe using the result. 
Here is the code for the IF Statement:

```
def sort_age(data):
    if (data["housing_median_age"] > 40) : 
        return ('Cat 5')
    elif ((30 <= data["housing_median_age"]) & (data["housing_median_age"] <= 40)) : 
        return ('Cat 4')
    elif ((20 <= data["housing_median_age"]) & (data["housing_median_age"] < 30)) :
        return ('Cat 3')
    elif (10 <= data["housing_median_age"] < 20) : 
        return ('Cat 2')
    elif (0 <= data["housing_median_age"] < 10) : 
        return ('Cat 1')
    else:
        return ('None')


# Here's the code for the new column:
p1data['age_category'] = p1data.apply(lambda x: sort_age(p1data), axis = 1)
```

The error message looks like this:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: use [numpy.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Comment: `rng = [0,10,20,30,40]
category = pd.cut(data["housing_median_age"], rng, labels=True,right=True)
`
It would be easier for me to add a new column of category values and aggregate them.

Answer (score 0):

To perform such categorization use a function deficated to this
case, namely *pd.cut*. The code can be:

```
p1data['age_category'] = pd.cut(p1data.housing_median_age,
    bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40.001, 200], right=False,
    labels=['Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3', 'Cat 4', 'Cat 5'])
```

Details:

- `bins` bin edges. Note some irregularity: All values are integers, but
  one of them is *40.001*, to provide that value of *40* will be
  categorized as *Cat 4*.
- `right=False` - to make bins open on the right side.

The advantage ot his solution is that the names assigned are just *Pandas*
**categories** and even if their names were not alpabetically ordered,
their logical order will be kept after any sorting.